# How to set state to child component in React Native

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, state

I'm trying to create a React Native app for managing categories and items. It uses **React Native Store** to save all local data. The app should not and will not use an internet API. It will be local and offline only.

I managed to push items to the DB when calling the `addCategory(title)` function but it does not update the state inside `categories.js`

Since there is a spectacular lack of documentation concerning the `state` in react-native, I wondered if anyone here knows how to make it update through the listview and when changing from the `categories` to the `items` to `details` Components.

I'm using React Native 0.26

**index.ios.js**:

```
... // default imports
import Store from 'react-native-store'

const categorieslist = require('./categories')
const DB = {
  'categories': Store.model('category'),
  'items': Store.model('item')
}

class testapp extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.reload()
  }
  reload() {
    DB.categories.find().then(resp => this.setState({
      categories: resp
    }))
  }
  addCategory(title) {
    var newTitle = title;
    DB.categories.add({
      title: newTitle,
      games: []
    })
    this.reload()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigatorIOS
          ...
          initialRoute={{
            component: categorieslist,
            title: 'Categories',
            rightButtonTitle: 'New',
            onRightButtonPress: () => {this.addCategory('title')},
            passProps: {
              categories: this.state.categories
            }
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
... // AppRegistry registerComponent and stuff
```

and **categories.js**:

```
... // default imports
class categories extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.categories)
    }
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.dataSource.getRowCount() === 0) {
      ... // shows 'no categories' screen
    } else {
      return(
        <ListView 
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <View><Text>{rowData}</Text></View>}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
module.exports = categories
```

Comment: Can you show how the `categories` data is being used by your datasource? Thanks.

Comment: @NaderDabit I updated the question. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State in react-native is the same as react (web). So you can refer to the documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

`state` is local to each component. In your `reload` method you `setState` to `this` which is the `testapp` Component and not the `categories` Component.

You must pass your state to the categories component via props.

Comment: You mean via passprops on the initialRoute?
I've tried that but since the DB object returns async, there is nothing in the state when I pass it to the categories Component.

Comment: Updated the question to incorporate passProps

Comment: When you update state/props the render method gets called (again) so it's fine that the objects are returned async. You need to have a read through the react docs to get a better understanding of how react works, as state and props is a fundamental.

Comment: After some more research I found out it actually has to do with NavigatorIOS. It apparently does not update any props inside the initialRoute via passProps. The Forums say "DO NOT USE NAVIGATORIOS" Which brings me back to zero since every tutorial I've found uses NavigatorIOS instead of Navigator.

So... that's... a nice introduction to React Native's update cycle...